# How to separate the sentences into boxes/frame - word by word?

Tags: frame

I tried something like

```
//Putting the sentence into array

NSString *list = (@"A book costs £50.,  Ken has saved £45.,  How much more does he need to save to buy the book?");
 NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

But the result wasn't what I want. I want each frame will contain a word. eg [A] [book] [costs] ...etc

```
    // to create a frame

    CGRect frame= CGRectMake(50, 60, 50, 50);
    comp *newBox = [[comp alloc] initWithFrame:frame ];
    [self.view addSubview:newBox]; 
    newBox.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor]
    This frame work fine, i just need to put the word in to each frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *list = (@"A book costs £50.  Ken has saved £45.  How much more does he need to save to buy the book?");
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: great! why i never thought about that. one more question any idea how to loop the each word into different frame? because what i got now is 10 boxes with a whole text on it. eg [(A, book, costs, ...)]  [(A, book, costs, ...)]  [(A, book, costs, ...)]